# Bower is only downloading bower.json but no real dependancy files

Tags: javascript, bower

My bower.json:

```
{
    "name": "best-project-ever",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "dependencies": {
        ...
        "xdomain": "0.6.11"
    },
    "devDependencies": {}
}
```

Running bower install, or bower install xdomain creates:

```
app/
    bower_components/
        xdomain/
            bower.json
```

But nothing else!  The bower.json file for xdomain clearly specifies including xdomain.js and xdomain.min.js  (ignoring everything BUT those files), but neither file is downloaded by bower.  Any ideas?  =)

```
{
  "name": "jpillora/xdomain",
  "version": "0.6.10",
  "main": "dist/0.6/xdomain.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "ignore": [
    "*",
    "!bower.json",
    "!dist/0.6/xdomain.js",
    "!dist/0.6/xdomain.min.js"
  ],
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`bower.json` spec](https://github.com/bower/bower.json-spec#ignore) says, that they are using the exact same syntax as `.gitignore`-files.

[`.gitignore`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) does specify the "!" as follows:

> An optional prefix "!" which negates the pattern; any matching file excluded by a previous pattern will become included again. **It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded**.

Note the bold sentence, which is exactly the problem.

Comment: Aha!  So it's not my fault, it's the xdomain bower.json that's got an issue   =)   I'll fork and fix it; see if it works for me then.